# Angularjs Validation and highlighting of input inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using angularjs here.
I have a table where using adds dynamic rows consisting of 2 inputs text on clicking the(+) button. Once they are done adding rows on the Done (submit) button I want to validate the inputs. I do see my validation is firing fine but its not highlighting the row which has error. Here is my code:

```
 <table class="table table-borderless" ng-if="options.length>0">      
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td class="bold">Key</td>
                <td class="bold">Value</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody style="border: none;">
            <tr ng-repeat="m in options">
                <td ng-class="{ 'has-error': paramForm['ctrlKey_' + {{$index}}].$invalid && (paramForm['ctrlValue_' + {{$index}}].$touched || paramForm.$submitted) }">
                    <input type="text" name="ctrlKey_{{$index}}" class="form-control" ng-model="m.optionText" required />                        
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="m.optionValue" required />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a class="btn btn-xs" ng-click="Remove($index)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I thought adding the below line would make my TD highlight to red but this does not work.

```
ng-class="{ 'has-error': paramForm['ctrlKey_' + {{$index}}].$invalid && (paramForm['ctrlValue_' + {{$index}}].$touched || paramForm.$submitted) }"
```

Anything missing here?

Updated:

I have created a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aman1981/uk21soj6/11/

Comment: Why are you hardcoding tables?

Comment: @SDH Sorry I dint get you, which line are you talking about?

Comment: Can anyone else lookinto this

Comment: You obviously don't want to list but the point is that your approach is wrong. Angular JS is modeled based on the MVC (model-view-controller) standard. Model is for your data. View is where you display your data. Controller is where you handle events and business logic. You need to deal with your data in the model and not on the view like you are trying to do.

Comment: I can help you more if you can explain what you are trying to do with your input validation. What type of validation are you trying to do??

Comment: I just want whem the user press the done button, it should highlight the rows which are empty.
I added jsfiddle demo also

Comment: Aahhh ok. That's pretty simple validation lol. Let me look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First move your buttons inside your form.

Secondly the name of the input you defined does not match to the one used in the TD ng-class

Correct these and let know.

Answer (score 0):

They added a new feature to HTML5 that does input validation. You simply add the following to any input tag:

```
<input required>
```

Documentation and Example

https://www.wufoo.com/html5/required-attribute/

Comment: Something conflicting. I'll look into it